# Is it possible to run python commands interactively through Dash?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I am thinking of using Dash for a potential project, however I am not fully aware of all the options and features that Dash can offer.

I was wondering if it is possible, that the is some kind of console in the Dash app that the user can execute commands on the spot.

E.g. Lets say that you have a data table called “stocks”. And the app shows the line graph of stock A or stock B that are inside the “stocks”. The user may want to see the line graph of A and B.

He could then execute in python
stocks[‘AnB’] = stocks[‘A’] + stocks[‘B’]

and update the data table stocks.
Something similar I think exists in SPSS.

Is that possible in Dash by plotly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Dash there are callback functions that, generally speaking, take inputs from the user (e.g. text fields), and use them to generate output which is then displayed in some element on the page (e.g. a graph). Several working examples can be found [here](https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started-part-2).

Technically, you *could* run an input from the user trough the python `eval` function, effectively executing a user's python script on the server, but this will come with **major** security concerns. I would recommend either writing your own string parser, allowing some basic arithmetic operations (as shown [here](http://blog.erezsh.com/how-to-write-a-calculator-in-70-python-lines-by-writing-a-recursive-descent-parser/) and [here](https://gist.github.com/ascv/5022712)), or coming up with some other creative way for users to tell the application which data to combine.